# C# with WPF Process.Start() on an MSI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I wanted to know why I am getting the following pop up:

[image]

When I use the following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "/i", @"MyApplication\MyMsi.msi");
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I can run the MSI by double clicking on it and it runs the application as it should, but whenever I try and spawn the MSI using the code above I just keep getting that Windows Installer pop up, can someone please help me get to the root of the problem here, or at least point me in the right direction...

Comment: I tried the code snippet you posted and it works fine for me.

Comment: Well the kick is this, if I run it through the command line manually it works... it is just when I try to do it through the application that I get this interesting response.

Comment: I copied your code exactly, pasted it, and I got a message that it couldn't find the msi. Then I hardcoded a path to an actual msi that I have and it launched fine. So I'm not sure why you are getting that window. Usually you get it when typing msiexec /? or if you enter incorrect parameters.

Comment: I attempted hard coding a path to the msi and go the same results so I do not think it has anything to do with the parameters.  So if it is not the parameters and it is not the msi iteself what else could be causing this problem?

Comment: XCopy deployment works since your are in your limit of an authenticated user or under admin privilege. This may no be the case if you try to install from a shared location ( in u'r intranet) or over wire ( internet). Therefore, it is wise to update the thread with the source of installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the way that I have it:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "/i", @"MyApplication\MyMsi.msi");
```

is actually

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "/i", @"MyApplication\My Msi.msi");
```

in my application, once I removed the space everything works great...I feel kinda silly that I missed this.  However, I am happy that I found out what the issue is.  Sorry for the confusion and thank you for the help.